# How to get the components from a json file from an observable in angular?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, rxjs, observable

Consider the code:

```
res: any;

getData(url: any) {
    this.res = this.http.get(url);
}

ngOnInit(): void {
     getData("url.com/file.json");
     console.log(this.res)
}
```

In the console I get

```
Observable {source: Observable, operator: ƒ}
```

How do I get the contents of the json file instead of an observable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the way you define the property and use the `httpClient` verbs in unconventional. If you want to assign the Http verb (i.e `GET`) to a property this property will hold an `Observable`, because `HttpClient` verbs return `Observables` in `Angular` and they are powered by `RxJS` under the hood.

Second, with this being said, if you want to get into the `JSON` part you need to subscribe to the `Observable`  i.e listen to the values that will be broadcasted by the `Observer`.

You have two ways to do that;

1 - As per Andrew description by assinging the `JSON` to the property within the subscription.

2- You keep the property assigned an `Observable` and use `async` pipe in your template.

Now, why you are getting `undefined` ? because during initialization of the component your asynchronous data has not been assinged yet to your property. Here, you have multiple options, including using a different lifecycle hook such as `ngAfterViewInit` or use a guard condition to check

```
if(res) { //stuff}
```

In all cases, you need a small refactoring for the unconventional way of handling Http calls as in your code snippets above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to the observable.

```
getData(url: any) {
    this.http.get(url).subscribe(result => { this.res = result; });
}
```

Comment: For me at least, that returns as undefined when console.log(this.res) how would I be able to read the contents of the json?